# printing a linked list using for loop in java

Tags: java, linked-list

I am learning linked list and wrote a sample code to understand the fundamentals. My code works, but is there another way to print out the list using a for loop without the while loop?

I cheated using the for loop I made, because I already knew the number of nodes in the list. Is there a different way of printing the list using a for loop?

```
public class FriendNode {
FriendNode next;
String name;

FriendNode(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.next = null;
}

public FriendNode(String name, FriendNode n)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.next = n;
}
public FriendNode getNext()
{
    return this.next;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    FriendNode g = new FriendNode("Bob");
    FriendNode o = new FriendNode("Alice");
    FriendNode k = new FriendNode("Tom");
    FriendNode m = new FriendNode("Day");
    g.next = o;
    o.next = k;
    k.next = m;
    m.next = null;
    FriendNode current=g;
    while(current!=null)
    {
        System.out.println(current);
        current = current.next;
    }
    for(int i =0; i<4;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(current);
        current = current.next;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Use an iterator or a for each loop.

Comment: Your second loop looks like it's going to throw a `NullPointerException` because it dereferences `current`, but the first loop will not exit until `current` is `null`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way :

```
for (FriendNode current=g; current != null; current = current.next) {
    System.out.println(current);
}
```

This is assuming that `g` is the first node, since that's how you initialized `current` when printing the list with the while loop.

It is essentially doing the same as the while loop, except that the initialization and increment are moved to the `for` expression, which make it more compact.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any difference using either the while or for loop to print out the list.

Comment: @user3497437 I don't think so, since it's the same code written in two different ways.

Answer (score 3):

The for loop doesn't have to work purely with ints, nor does it have to be incremented or decremented. This is also valid:

```
for (FriendNode ii = g; ii != null; ii = ii.next)
{
    System.out.println(ii);
}
```

The potential problem with both, though, is that you run the risk of an infinite loop - if you set m.next to g, both the while loop and the for loop will execute forever. If you needed to, you could guard against that by keeping a reference to the FriendNode (g) you've started with, and breaking out of the loop if i is g.

Comment: Thank. Its there a major difference using the while or for loop

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Iterable and use "the other kind" of for loop

```
    for (Friend f : new FriendList(g)) {
        System.out.println(f.name);
    }
```

I've created a `FriendList` that uses the `FriendNode`. And stuck a `Friend` object inside the `FriendNode` rather than just a string. IMO that will allow you better extensiblity going forwards.

The implementation looks like this:

```
import FriendList.Friend;


public class FriendList implements Iterable<Friend> {

    public static class Friend {
        public Friend(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        String name;
    }

    public static class FriendNode {
        FriendNode next;
        Friend friend;

        FriendNode(String name)
        {
            this.friend = new Friend(name);
            this.next = null;
        }

        public FriendNode(String name, FriendNode n)
        {
            this.friend = new Friend(name);
            this.next = n;
        }
        public FriendNode getNext()
        {
            return this.next;
        }
    }

    public FriendList(FriendNode n) {
        first = n;
    }

    @Override public Iterator<Friend> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<Friend>() {

            FriendNode node = first;

            @Override public boolean hasNext() {
                return node != null;
            }

            @Override public Friend next() {
                Friend f = node.friend;
                node = node.next;
                return f;
            }

            @Override public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        };
    }

    FriendNode first;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FriendNode g = new FriendNode("Bob");
        FriendNode o = new FriendNode("Alice");
        FriendNode k = new FriendNode("Tom");
        FriendNode m = new FriendNode("Day");
        g.next = o;
        o.next = k;
        k.next = m;
        m.next = null;

        FriendList list = new FriendList(g);

        for (Friend f : list) {
            System.out.println(f.name);
        }
    }

}
```